# VXLAN does not work when brought up initially

Tags: networking, ipv6

I am trying to get an overlay network working using VXLAN. It is all in all a fairly simple setup, but for whatever strange reason refuses to work correctly when brought up.

I have two (well, half a dozen really, but that is irrelevant here) hosts, A and B. Both are configured similarly:

```
ip -6 link add vx1 type vxlan id 99 dstport 4789 local <local-ipv6-address>
bridge fdb append 00:00:00:00:00:00 dev vx1 dst <remote-ipv6-address>
ip link set up dev vx1
ip -6 addr add <random-ula>::10/64 dev vx1
```

except obviously with local/remote swapped, and with different addresses in the last step.

I have ping6 running from A to B, and as soon as the interface is good to go, I can see traffic on host B (with `tcpdump`). But there are no responses from B to A. The situation is similar to [Why linux does not respond to ICMP Request from VxLAN?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/671149/why-linux-does-not-respond-to-icmp-request-from-vxlan) but that does not help. This happens both after I bring up the interface by hand, or by having a similar config in `/etc/network/interfaces`. What does however "fix" the situation is if I send even a single ping from B to A, and suddenly everything magically works.

I've checked routing, iptables, fdb and anything I can think of. Nothing in any of the configs seems to change between simply bringing up the interface and sending the first "fix ping". My problem is of course reboots, so is there anything I can check and possibly do to fix this properly? One option is sending ping messages to all the other hosts in the overlay, but that seems hacky at best, and hardly a reliable solution. Especially when building a larger overlay..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your case, but in my case, it was a misconfiguration from one of the end of the vxlan. The forwarding database (which you can look at using `bridge fdb` ) one node (A) was containing a wrong information: in particular the 00:00:00:00:00:00 MAC Address was (wrongly) said to be accessible at node A's IP address, instead of being accessible at the IP address of node B.

Appending the correct values using `bridge fdb append 00:00:00:00:00:00 dev <VXLAN INTERFACE> dst <IP ADDRESS>` and removing the wrong forwarding rules made it work.

The ping is triggering a "correct" behaviour because it allows the peer to discover the IP <-> MAC address mapping, without having to relay on MAC broadcast.